# How to determine my IP address on a split-tunnel VPN?

Tags: ip, ip-address, vpn

I would like to find my IP address that other machines on a corporate split-tunnel VPN see me as. Is there a way to determine that from terminal?

Answer (score 1):

Traceroute will show you the path your traffic is following. With split tunneling, a traceroute to an internet IP should not pass your VPN gateway.

Another way to make sure traffic to the internet is not going through the tunnel is by visiting a website which shows your IP address (eg IPinfo, WhatsmyIP, ip2location)

On command line run

```
curl ipinfo.io
```

sample output

```
{
  "ip": "104.XX.XX.XX",
  "hostname": "rs2",
  "city": "Los Angeles",
  "region": "California",
  "country": "US",
  "loc": "34.0584,-118.2780",
  "postal": "91017",
  "org": "AS3243"
}
```

Comment: Love this answer

Comment: This doesn't answer the OP's question.  The question was which IP address the other machines on the corporate network would see from the OP's machine, not what IP address other websites outside the corporate network see.

Answer (score 0):

There's probably various ways to do this, but this is one that comes to mind:

1. Make sure you are on the VPN, then ping a domain that your VPN will tunnel to (in your split tunnel), to get the IP address of the destination:

```bash
> ping example.com
PING example.com (93.184.216.34): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 93.184.216.34: icmp_seq=0 ttl=55 time=16.755 ms
```

2. Start a `tcpdump` watching the IP address:

```bash
> sudo tcpdump host 93.184.216.34
```

3. Now in another tab in your terminal, hit the endpoint with some client like cURL:

```bash
> curl 93.184.216.34
```

4. The first domain in your tcpdump output will be your VPN address.

```bash
Password:
tcpdump: data link type PKTAP
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on pktap, link-type PKTAP (Apple DLT_PKTAP), capture size 262144 bytes
18:59:55.675210 IP client40717.vpn.example.com.56106 > ...
```

5. Now just ping that domain to get your IP address:

```bash
>  ping client40717.vpn.example.com
PING client40717.vpn.example.com (175.33.210.205): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 175.33.210.205: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=4.937 ms
64 bytes from 175.33.210.205: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.115 ms
64 bytes from 175.33.210.205: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.130 ms
```

You can also just check your VPN client. They usually display this info. For example, Cisco's AnyConnect has a small icon at the bottom to get network info. You'll see the "Client Address":

[image: List item]
[image]